# every one-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is locally $f\,dg$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms

I have read (*McDuff-Salamon, Introduction to Symplectic Topology*) that every smooth one-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be locally written as $f\, dg$ for $f, g$ smooth functions. To my embarrassment I don't seem to be able to prove this. Can anyone help me out?

**Some ideas:**
This is equivalent to saying that for all functions $\alpha, \beta$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, there locally exist solutions to
\begin{align}
f(x, y) \partial_x g(x, y) &= \alpha(x, y) \\
f(x, y) \partial_y g(x, y) &= \beta(x, y)
\end{align}
So it seems that it is necessary to be able to solve the PDE
$$
\frac{\partial_x g}{\partial_y g} = \gamma
$$
for arbitrary functions $\gamma$. But we also need to worry about the case where $\beta$ is zero at some points...

Comment: have you tried mimicking the proof of Poincare's lemma ? This is just Poincare's lemma in case your smooth $1$-form is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precise claim is that if $\omega$ is **non-zero** at $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $\omega$ can be written locally around $p$ as $\omega = f dg$. To see that this holds, choose some non-zero vector field $X$ such that $\omega(X) = 0$ locally around $p$. Since $X \neq 0$, one can find a coordinate system $(x,y)$ around $p$ with $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ (i.e "flatten the vector field"). Writing $\omega = \alpha dx + \beta dy$ we see that $0 = \omega(X) = \alpha$ so around $p$ we have $\alpha \equiv 0$ and hence $\omega = \beta dy$.

---

To see that this is not always possible when $\omega|_{p} = 0$, consider the form $\omega = -y dx + x dy$ around the origin. If we can write

$$ -y dx + x dy = fdg = f(x,y)g_x(x,y) dx + f(x,y) g_y(x,y) dy $$

then we get

$$ -y = f(x,y) g_x(x,y), \,\,\, x = f(x,y) g_y(x,y). $$

By plugging in $(x,0)$ in the first equality, we get $f(x,0) g_x(x,0) = 0$ and by plugging in $(0,y)$ in the second equality, we get $f(0,y) g_y(0,y) = 0$. Since $f(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $(x,y) \neq 0$ we get that $g_x(x,0) = 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $g_y(0,y) = 0$ for all $y \neq 0$. By continuity, we must have $g_x(0,0) = g_y(0,0) = 0$ (or $dg|_{(0,0)} = 0$). Since

$$ d\omega = 2(dx \wedge dy) = df \wedge dg $$

and $dg|_{(0,0)} = 0$ while $d\omega|_{(0,0)} \neq 0$, we get a contradiction.

Away from the origin, we can always write $\omega = r^2 d\theta$.

Comment: Note that since $\beta \neq 0$ around $p$, this also shows that $\frac{1}{\beta} \omega$ is exact. In other words, any non-zero form $\omega$ has an integrating factor (a function $h$ such that $h\omega$ is exact). In terms of differential equations, this shows that any ODE of the form $P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0$ where at least one of $P,Q$ is non-zero at $(x_0,y_0)$ can be solved locally around $(x_0,y_0)$ using an integration factor.